# AngularJS Default Home Page Routing Url

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm using AngularJS for my front end web framework and was wondering how I can change the routing of my states so that when i go to my website, it would say (for example) abc.com rather than abc.com/home. I am using StateProvider to switch between views and this as default home url

```
state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
}).

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

I have this in my index.html

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

I want to keep my home page content in a separate file from index.html, yet always not show that url so I would not see "/home" at all whenever I use the website. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
state('home', {
url: '/',
templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
})
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URL in the route definition to `/` instead of `/home`.